# Pass parameters to prop function without using an arrow function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, arrow-functions, react-props

I've heard that passing an arrow function as a prop is not ideal because it creates a new function every time which will lead to performance issues. However, I'm not entirely sure how to completely move away from them, as can be seen by the example below:

```
class Home extends Component {

    onCardPress = (message) =>{
        alert(message)
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <Card 
                    onCardPress={this.onCardPress}
                    message="Hello world!"
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
}

class Card extends Component {
    render(){
        const { onCardPress , message } = this.props;
        return(
            <TouchableOpacity
                activeOpacity={0.8}
                onPress={()=>{onCardPress(message)}}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

I have tried changing `onPress` in `Card` to be `onPress={onCardPress(message)}`, but I know this doesn't work because I am invoking the function rather than passing a function object to the `onPress` of `TouchableOpacity`. What is the 'proper' way or best practice to remove the arrow function in `TouchableOpacity` while still being able to pass the `message` parameter from the parent component `Home`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid arrow function, you have to use `bind()`. Arrow functions will [automatically bind "this"](https://medium.com/tfogo/advantages-and-pitfalls-of-arrow-functions-a16f0835799e).

```
  class Home extends Component {

      constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.onCardPress = this.onCardPress.bind(this);
      }

      onCardPress (message) {
        alert(message)
      }

      render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <Card 
                    onCardPress={this.onCardPress}
                    message="Hello world!"
                />
            </View>
        )
      }
  }



class Card extends Component {
    render(){
        const { onCardPress , message } = this.props;
        return(
            <TouchableOpacity
                activeOpacity={0.8}
                onPress={onCardPress(message)}
            />
        )
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
class Card extends Component {
    pressHandler = () => this.props.onCardPress(this.props.message);

    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
                activeOpacity={0.8}
                onPress={this.pressHandler.bind(this)}
            />
        );
    } }
```

Comment: Just wondering, is this functionally the same as the arrow function version i.e. performance wise its the same? Or does this avoid the performance issues of using arrow functions?

Comment: There is a small benefit in that you are not creating a new function every time the event handler is triggered, however this is pretty negligible overall.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the issue lies with calling `bind` inside of `render`, or returning the handler from yet another lambda, as this will create a new function each time. The conventional way to get around this problem is to bind your handler functions elsewhere -- like in the constructor. In your case, that could look like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    ....
    this.onCardPress = this.onCardPress.bind(this);
}

...

<Card 
   onCardPress={this.onCardPress}
   message="Hello world!"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given you alternative option as arrow function already answered in above post.

```
class Card extends Component {
   onClick = () => {
      const { onCardPress, message } = this.props;
      onCardPress(message);
    }
    render(){
        const { onCardPress , message } = this.props;
        return(
            <TouchableOpacity
                activeOpacity={0.8}
                onPress={this.onClick}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the message prop because you can access it anywhere in the component.
Just supply a function in the onPress prop. And in that function, just access the message prop of the component.

```
class Home extends Component {
  onCardPress = (message) => {
    alert(message)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Card
          onCardPress={this.onCardPress}
          message="Hello world!"
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

class Card extends Component {
  onClick = () => {
    const { message, onCardPress } = this.props;
    onCardPress(message);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        activeOpacity={0.8}
        onPress={this.onClick}
      />
    )
  }
}
```